# Drop down menu broken in Opera

Tags: jquery, css, opera, drop-down-menu

I just happen to check my site in Opera which I (stupidly) hadn't done for a few weeks, only to discover that my drop-down menu is completely broken. When I hover over a parent item, all the menu items move around so the menu breaks. This doesn't happen in any other browser that I've checked.

Can anyone see anything that may be causing it in my code?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

$('#nav li').hover(
   function () {
   $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
   }, 
   function () {
   $('ul', this).slideUp(100);         
   }
);
```

});

CSS

```
ul#nav {list-style: none; white-space: nowrap; float: right; position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 0;}
ul#nav li {display: inline; margin-right: 10px; padding: 0 10px; position: relative; text-transform: uppercase;}
ul#nav li.last {margin-right: 0;}
ul#nav li.slash {padding: 0;}
ul#nav li a {text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 12px; color: black; padding: 10px 0 10px 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
ul#nav li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
ul#nav li a.active {font-style: normal; text-decoration: underline;}
ul#nav li a.active:hover {color: black;}
ul#nav li.parent_selected, ul#nav li.selected {font-style: italic;}

#nav li ul {position: absolute; top: 26px; right: 0; padding: 20px 0 10px 20px; background-color: #f6f6f6; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align: right; z-index: 999;}
#nav li ul li {display:block; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 0;}
#nav li ul li a {text-transform: none; font-size: 12px; color: black;}
#nav li ul li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

As it seems to be working in all the major browsers (except Opera) I'm hesitant about fiddling with it until I no where it's going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that we can see the problem, rather than trying to infer it from your jQuery and CSS?

Comment: Thanks David here it is  http://jsfiddle.net/WctpW/

Comment: Strange as fiddle seems to be working in Opera!

Answer (score 0):

I have been there before (and often): Opera (which is the right thing to do anyways) expect everything to be explicity. While I can get away with missing stuff in just about any other browser, if I do not, for example, do a "clear both" or "display block" in one item, everything gets out of sync in Opera.

Check every item for with, height, floating, etc.

PS: I did not even look at your code.